# script/way to open a file in notepad++, reformat and save it

Tags: xml, xml-formatting

i have this xml file. depending on what i use to open it (wordpad, notepad, notepad++), it opens differently. for example, if i open it using wordpad, it opens as one long line. if i open it with notepad, it is multiple line but not nicely formatted. if i open with notepad++, it is multiple line but still not nicely formatted unless i use the xml plugin.

for example, i was to see file in this format,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and not in one long line like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading>  
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

so my question is, does anyone have a better idea on,

1. how to open this file, reformat it nicely in xml file, save it and close it? 
   or
2. how to write some sort of script, that will open this file using notepad++, use that xml plugin, save it and close it? as i mentioned earlier, i have tried once manually on one file and i was successfully able to format it nicely in xml format.

any help would be nice and please let me know if you have any questions.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind -- either using a proper XML editor (will depend on your platform), or passing it first through an XML pretty-printer (xmllint should be available whatever your platform).

Comment: hello asmecher - thanks for your suggestion but i am trying to do this for thousands and thousands files so opening one at a time and doing this will be laborious. i am looking for script that could do this for me.

Comment: You can script xmllint pretty easily; it's a command-line tool.

Comment: hello asmecher - isnt xmllint for only linux? i am looking for something on windows xp.

Comment: xmllint should be available for pretty much any platform; google "xmllint for windows".